# how do I POST two consecutive html tags to PHP script

Tags: php, html, forms

I am sending cms updates from a textarea edited by CKeditor to a PHP handler using jQuery. The POST contains the HTML for the page. Not a problem, or so I thought.
Now when I send two consecutive tags like `<p><strong>`  or even just `><` the server throws a forbidden error.

I haven't had a problem with another site I built using the same principles, running on the same server, and I tried the consecutive tags scenario without a hitch.

I built a simple test(code below, a form with a textarea to POST to a PHP handler that echoes the results of the POST. Even if I don't even read the POST content the server still throws the error.
So it would appear that I have to process the HTML before POSTing.

I cannot for the life of me see what is different in the site that works as there is no data handling before POSTing.

Does anyone know of this problem, and any solutions?

Oh! and it works fine on my WAMP server(5.3.5)(public server is 5.2.17), so is there a PHP setting I could look at over-riding?

And now we have entered the twilight zone. I changed the textarea field name from `name="test1"` to `S` and there are no hitches??? So I now have an odd solution but this may not be the end of it, so If anyone is aware of what the issue could be, I'd be very thankful if not amazed.

Code:
post-form.php

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Post Form</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="post-print.php" method="post">

<textarea name="test1" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
<!--name this and the php code text1 and it works-->
<textarea name="test2" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
<textarea name="test3" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>


<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

post-print.php

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>Print result:</p>
<p><?php echo $_POST['test1']; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $_POST['test2']; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $_POST['test3']; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have some kind of intrusion detection system like phpIDS running? That might prevent the usage of POST variables containing html tags.

Comment: there is nothing at all installed by me but it is a shared server so I don't know if there's anything installed by the hosts. How could I check.

Comment: @Bluebox — Ask the host.

Comment: And this is why I loath server level XSS defences, they are like trimming bonsai tress with a lawnmower.

Comment: Yes I agree. Having gone over a few different scenarios I think this could be a host/server specific issue. I will have to relay all this to them to see if they have a clue.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to be sure about what are the values that your script containing the form is passing.

Change your script "post-print.php" (or "update_divs.php", not clear from your sample) to be something like this:

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: Sorry form action was changed to test and I forgot to change back for this post. Even if post-print consists entirely of one line `    <?php print_r($_POST); ?>` it still fails with Forbidden:
You don't have permission to access /server/path/post-print.php on this server.